# get facebook posts (and older posts) without access token

Tags: php, facebook

i already found a way to get posts without an access token:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=121136164607942
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=121136164607942

With the URLs above you can get the newest posts, but what about the older ones? I basicly wanna achive what facebook already got (load the newest posts and then there will be a button "load more"). Including an IFrame is not an option. I want to make the facebook posts responsive.

Does somebody know if theres a way to get the older posts? I already tried adding &offset=10 but it doesnt seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old Page Feed endpoint will stop working soon. Use `/v2.3/{page_id}/feed` instead, then you can also use the `since` parameter.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_90_day_deprecations
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

> **Page RSS Feed endpoint** - at https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php is now deprecated and will stop returning data from June 23, 2015. Developers should call the Graph API's `/v2.3/{page_id}/feed` endpoint instead. This returns JSON rather than RSS/XML.

Comment: So basicly there no way to get data from facebook without an access token? I mean you can see posts as a user for example: https://www.facebook.com/MicrosoftDE
So why isnt there a way to get the raw data using the graph without any login? You could also just open the page via php and search for the data by yourself. But thats not what i actually want.

Comment: An Access Token shouldn't be a problem, or? Just create an app (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), go to Graph Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), choose your newly created app and click "Get App Token". Done.

Comment: No its not a problem. But i was searching an option without the access token (read the title). So basicly its impossible after the june 23, 2015?

Comment: I read the title, and I told you in my answer that the current way of doing this will stop working soon. It's impossible after June 23, 2015.